# Accept all mail for a domain (from everywhere), forward mail for selected recipients to specific addresses, relay all else to a specific host

Tags: centos6, sendmail, mail-forwarding

What I want to do is set up a sendmail server that accepts mail from everyone to a particular domain (say, `example.com`), then for a list of defined recipients sends that mail onto specified third-party addresses, and relays everything else onto a specific IP address.

I've tried this:

```
[root@splitter mail]# cat relay-domains 
example.com
[root@splitter mail]# cat virtusertable
divert.test@example.com  new.recipient@example.co.uk
```

and forwarding of most of the domain works fine - it's delivered to the host specified by `example.com`'s MX - but the exception (`divert.test@example.com`) is ignored

I've tried this:

```
[root@splitter mail]# cat local-host-names 
example.com
[root@splitter mail]# cat mailertable
example.com      esmtp:[1.2.3.4]
[root@splitter mail]# cat virtusertable
divert.test@example.com  new.recipient@example.co.uk
```

and then the exception mail is correctly split off, but any other user is bounced locally (`User unknown`).  I've tried adding this to `virtusertable`:

```
@example.com           %1@example.com
```

but (probably unsurprisingly) this results in `rewrite: excessive recursion (max 50), ruleset canonify` errors.

I'd prefer sendmail-based solutions, because I can try those quickly.  If I don't get any luck with that, I'll open this up to other MTAs.  If anyone has any ideas about how to do this, I'd really appreciate them.

Comment: This is easy with postfix and relay maps, any reason you want send mail?

Comment: @JacobEvans as I said, I have sendmail set up and ready to go - I can try this now.  If I do it with another MTA, I have to learn that MTA from scratch, and set it up.  But if It can't be done in sendmail, I'll have to accept that price.

Comment: OK that I understand, I never spent a ton of time in sendmail so I just wanted to know why.  Thanks & hope you get an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
# Assuming example.com is in $=w
LOCAL_RULE_0
Ruser1 < @ example.com. > $*    $@ newuser1 < @somewhere.com. > 
Ruser2 < @ example.com. > $*    $@ newuser2 < @somewhereelse.com. > 
R$* < @ example.com. > $*    $#esmtp $@ [1.2.3.4] $: $1 < @ example.com. > $2
```

Naturally this does not scale well if you want to make it workable for more than 10 users and you need to make it work with a map, but I've stopped being a Postmaster since 5/2014 and I am a little rusty. I can make it work with an external map if you like though.

As always remember that in your `sendmail.mc` the left hand side of a rule is separated from right hand side with tabs and not spaces, so **do not copy-paste**.  Also remember to rebuild your `sendmail.cf` afterwards and test using `sendmail -bt`:

```
> 3,0 user1@example.com
```

If all works as expected restart sendmail.

Comment: Works in address test mode, but gives `User unknown` when sending mail to the exceptions via SMTP.  Thanks hugely for trying, though!  Not having a map is no problem, as I only need this to work for 5-10 users, and only for a short while.

Comment: Is the recipient SMTP server (1.2.3.4) configured to accept email for those addresses?

Comment: In your example above, do you mean `somewhere.com`'s server?  If so, then yes, it is - but the mail doesn't get that far, my relay box instantly returns `<user1@example.com>... User unknown`.  Also in your example above, 1.2.3.4 isn't the problem - it's the exceptions that aren't handled, not the rule (if you see what I mean).

Comment: Hm, I see what you mean. Since example.com is a local domain, user1 must be a user of the system (or an alias). Please add MODIFY_MAILER_FLAGS(`LOCAL', `-w')dnl in your sendmail.mc and see what happens (The quotes and backticks are a bit messed up here in the comment, but you know how to write this). If it works I will update the answer

Comment: Also add example.com in local-host-names, not relay-domains

Comment: The second bit, I'd already done.  The first doesn't help (and thanks for your faith that I can use sendmail's weird balanced back/forward ticks!); it still tries **local** delivery to newuser1.  It's almost as if, having made the decision to use Mlocal, it can't be persuaded out of it merely be substituting an off-system address.

Comment: Like I said, I am a bit rusty. I made a minor change in the rules. I had forgotten the < > on the right hand side.  If this does not work, I'll fire up a VM to test myself.

Comment: Those angle brackets are the charm!  I'd almost forgotten one could edit `sendmail.cf` *directly*.  Thank you so much!